# Notification number on icon

Tags: android, notifications

I want to make number of notifications on icon increases when I insert row in DB. I m using phpmyadmin mysql DB. Is there some way to get information after inserting (not push up notification). I know that I can check every minute if DB is updated, but I dont like that way. 
Does anyone have suggestion?

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you want "make number of notifications on icon increases" ?? or  "way to get information after inserting"?? Two completely different questions.

Comment: When I add some row in table in DB I want to get that information, and to incrase number of notifications on icon. I just want to get that information, not to send push up notification after inserting in DB.

Comment: OK, I understand now. You are inserting a row into your MySQL database from an external source. You want your App to "somehow know" that a row has been inserted. Unfortunately, with MySql you most poll the database to see if anything has been added. You might want to take a look at Firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. You can just send payload without notification, just filled with data.

```
$fields = array("data"=>array("KatalogID"=>$catalogID), "to"=>"/topics/all");
```